# Python asyncio refuses to acknowledge new event loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

This is my first time playing with asyncio on Python, please bear with me. I have a for loop that integrates async, and what *seemed* very logical to me is apparently completely wrong.

At the end of the loop, I close the loop, then create and set a new loop to continue the script. However, I keep getting the "Event loop is closed" runtime error--but not all the time, maybe about 2/3rds of the time.

What am I missing here?

```
try:
    for data in targetData:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        graph = loop.run_until_complete(load_graph(data))
        paths = bellman_ford(graph, unique_paths=True)

        for path in paths:
            try:
                print_opportunity_for_path(graph, path)
            except Exception as exc:
                print ('Error: {}'.format(exc))

        asyncio.wait(1)
        loop.close()
        newLoop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        assert(loop != newLoop)
        asyncio.set_event_loop(newLoop)
```

It's driving me insane :) I've even gone as far as adding a random wait and probably unnecessary assert.

Edit: Seems like a third-party library that's causing the headaches..?

```
    Exception ignored in: <bound method Exchange.__del__ of <ccxt.async.gdax.gdax object at 0x7fe09c07b0f0>>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/hyoon/scripts/arb/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ccxt/async/base/exchange.py", line 64, in __del__
        self.asyncio_loop.run_until_complete(self.session.close())
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 444, in run_until_complete
        self._check_closed()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 358, in _check_closed
        raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
    RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
    /home/hyoon/scripts/arb/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/peregrinearb/utils/data_structures.py:62: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ClientSession.close' was never awaited
      heapq.heappush(self.heap, (pri, d))
    Unclosed client session
    client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7fe09c07b400>
    Unclosed connector
    connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7fe0a79cc160>, 696463.579907268), (<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7fe09aea6898>, 696463.613516469), (<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7fe09aea69b0>, 696463.615550519), (<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7fe09aea6a20>, 696463.616189468), (<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7fe09af0a630>, 696463.616714588), (<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7fe09aea6940>, 696463.621970396), (<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7fe09aea6860>, 696463.622567727), (<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7fe09aea6908>, 696463.624466974), (<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7fe09aea6978>, 696463.625720629), (<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7fe09aea68d0>, 696463.630833432), (<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7fe09aea69e8>, 696463.635552591), (<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x7fe09aea6a58>, 696463.639611507)]']
    connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x7fe09c07b390>
    Fatal write error on socket transport
    protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x7fe09aea6ba8>
    transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport fd=7>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 761, in write
        n = self._sock.send(data)
    OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
    Fatal error on SSL transport
    protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x7fe09aea6ba8>
    transport: <_SelectorSocketTransport closing fd=7>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 761, in write
        n = self._sock.send(data)
    OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: Why you need to create a new event loop? And where do you close the loop? I cannot see it. And, `asyncio.wait` is a corotine.

Comment: @Sraw If I don't create a new loop I get the error "Unclosed client session"

Upon investigation, it appears that a third party library is closing the connection causing the trouble... Added above

Comment: Have you tried investigating which library opens the client session and whether it has an API to close it? It might be a better long-term solution than hiding the problem by switching to a new event loop each time around.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - did you find a fix?